# Coq syntax for defining lemmas

Tags: coq

I can see the different syntax of Coq for defining lemmas. For example, `Lemma plus_n_O: forall n:nat, n = n + 0.` and `Lemma plus_n_O n: n = n + 0.` both define that the sum of zero by any number is equal to the number. How these definitions differ? Or this is a new feature of Coq to remove `forall` quantifier from definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two definitions are essentially equivalent.  Generally speaking, any statement of the form

```
Lemma foo x y z : P.
Proof.
(* ... *)
```

is equivalent to

```
Lemma foo : forall x y z, P.
Proof.
intros x y z.
(* ... *)
```